# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime leading with zero

Tags: c#, datetime

how can time be handled i.e. leading with zero in C#. In DB, column (i.e. last_time) is numeric where time is `60000` (for numeric first zero not available). Whenever, executing below command with converting in datetime, getting ERROR.

> > ERROR : “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”.

```
DateTime exetb = DateTime.ParseExact(last_time, "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What is your `last_time` string. You should convert the numeric `last_time` to string by `last_time.ToString()`

Comment: @Karan Desai, i have already converted numeric to string, but getting same error. > string converted_last_time = last_time.ToString();

Comment: What is the required value of time after converting "60000"?

Comment: @ Rahul Hendawe,  after converting required value is '060000'.

Comment: Is this value a Unix timestamp or a TimeSpan instead of DateTime? (Do you mean 60000 ms for example?)

Comment: `Hmmss` allows hours either *with* leading zero or *without*

Comment: @Mithgroth, it is hhmmss.

Comment: Why do you keep time values in numeric data type to begin with?

Comment: try this => `DateTime exetb = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("0{0}", last_time), "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @helal Sorry, I'm confused. Are you trying to spesify an amount of time? Because there is no 60th hour in the clock? What is the unit of this "60000"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right `60000` means `6:00:00` (Today 6 AM), it seems that you are looking for `H` hour representation: hour in 0..23 range with *optional* leading zero:

```
 // last_time is of type String; if not put last_time.ToString()    
 DateTime exetb = DateTime.ParseExact(last_time, "Hmmss", ...
```

Your current implementation has `HH` hour pattern which means *mandatory* leading zero. If you are looking for *amount of time* (e.g. `60000` means `60000` seconds) you should use `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`